# Shooting .mp4 with the CANON EOS 600D

Tags: mp4

Please help. I need to know if I can shoot videos with my CANON EOS 600D in mp4 format. I don't want to go full HD .mov. I just want the camera to record small .mp4 videos - in order for me to load the footage onto a website immediately after shooting. Any advice will be great. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

You can find the manual for your camera [here](http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/cameras/digital_slr/eos_600d.aspx). What you're looking for is how to change the resolution and frame rate of your recordings, you'll find instructions on that on page 150. (Some Canon camera models also have an option to change the bitrate and the compression mode; I didn't find any information on that in the manual, so I assume it doesn't have those options, but you should check that on your camera). A lower frame rate and resolution will result in a smaller video file, but keep in mind that this will also reduce video quality. I would recommend you record a high-quality video and use some software to export a smaller version to upload onto the internet later on. There are several free programs that will alow you to do that.

`.mov` and `.mp4` are only file containers (check [my answer here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/how-are-video-and-audio-streams-placed-in-container-files-and-what-interrelati/15824#15824) for a detailed explanation). If your camera doesn't have an option to change the used container format (which the Canon camera models I know don't), you're gonna have to live with whatever it's offering you. Again, you can reencode a given recording into a different (container) format (pretty easy) or remux it (slightly more difficult) with free software.